# Android: reading two databases in the same activity

Tags: android, sql

I have created several databases, and I am trying to allow the user to view the information from all databases.  In the code below, you can see that I am opening, grabbing info from, and closing each database.  The problem is that it is only showing me information from the first database called, and putting that into both TextViews.  I cannot seem to find a way around this or why it is happening.  Any suggestions?

```
public class SQLView extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //TODO
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);

    ViewAbsData();
    ViewBicepsData();

 }


public void ViewAbsData(){
    //list ab exercises in database
    TextView tvAbs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.absDatabaseView);
    AbsDatabase absinfo = new AbsDatabase(SQLView.this);
    try {
        absinfo.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String absdata = absinfo.getData();
    absinfo.close();
    tvAbs.setText(absdata);
}



public void ViewBicepsData(){
    //list biceps exercises in database
    TextView tvBiceps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bicepsDatabaseView);
    BicepsDatabase bicepsinfo = new BicepsDatabase(SQLView.this);
    try {
        bicepsinfo.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String bicepsdata = bicepsinfo.getData();
    bicepsinfo.close();
    tvBiceps.setText(bicepsdata);
}
 }
```

Comment: could you explain me why more than 1 database, i think one is enough.

Comment: Do you need two databases, or just two tables in one database? And, generally, in android, developers tend to use SQLiteOpenHelper with a singleton pattern

Comment: Do you mean more than one database or more than one table? If it's more than one table (which is fine) you just query it as normal. Your tables can all be made and managed in your DatabaseHandler class

Comment: Is it possible that both of your databases have the same info (i.e. a data-write bug)? You would need to look at both your databases with either FireFox's add-on for SQLite or the sqlite3 tool. +1 to MichalK for the SQLiteOpenHelper reference.

Comment: I made several databases for exercises for each body part (ex. abs, biceps, etc).  I am pretty new to SQL so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this.  I actually didn't even think of creating more than one table in the same database.  I feel that having separate db classes is cleaner, but if it doesn't work I will switch it up.  Do you think using several tables in the same database would solve my problem?

Comment: One database is more than enough.  Constructed properly the tables will provide efficient relational access to the data.

Comment: thank you that worked great.  if someone wants to provide this as an answer, i will give you credit for the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One database is more than enough. Constructed properly the tables will provide efficient relational access to the data.